# Does the confidence interval for Poisson rate contain the sample mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, mean, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$ be iid random variables from $Poisson(\lambda)$. The confidence interval for $\lambda$ with confidence level $1-\alpha$ is

$$  \frac{1}{2N} \chi^2 \left(\alpha/2; 2 \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right) \le \lambda \le  \frac{1}{2N} \chi^2 \left(1-\alpha/2; 2 \sum_{i=1}^N X_i+2 \right) .$$

The sample mean
$$\overline{X} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$
is an unbiased estimator for the parameter $\lambda$ but is it necessarily contained in the above confidence interval? In other words, is it true that
$$  \frac{1}{2N} \chi^2 \left(\alpha/2; 2 N \overline{X}\right) \le \overline{X} \le  \frac{1}{2N} \chi^2 \left(1-\alpha/2; 2 N \overline{X}+2 \right) $$
for all sample sizes $N$ and for all $\alpha \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: See what happens in the limit as $\alpha\to1.$